# Read VC++ PDB source files bounds and lines

Tags: visual-c++, pdb-files

So I reverse engenering a program which have a PDB included with functions, source files and global variables symbols. I use IDA PRO which includes the functions and variables names from the PDB but I don't know to what source file each function belongs. Also somewhere I read that this file also includes an compiler paramters for each source file. The problem is nowhere in the internet I can't find a tool which read all the information from the Program DataBase. Also I founs a book which describes the format (Undocumented Windows 2000 Secrets). Does somebody knows a program which may help me?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\DIA SDK\Samples\DIA2Dump". It uses [DIA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8) to access the PDB and can show a lot of info.

If you'd rather not mess with compiling stuff, you can try **dbh.exe** from Debugging Tools for Windows. Its [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540441) are somewhat cryptic, but it does have functionality to show source file/line info.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The dbh.exe help me a lot.